# how to do image analysis on android camera api

Tags: android, opencv, android-camerax

I am currently working on making an document scanner app that draws the page detected in the camera preview. For this, I have been exploring many camera APIs and seem to find CameraX the easiest since it reduces the work for the developer a lot. Some issues that I am facing are:

1. Almost all of the examples of CameraX with ImageAnalysis are in
   Kotlin. Even then, they all seem to just do rudimentary analysis
   such as calculating the luminosity. What I want to do is draw a
   border around the page in the preview itself. Can someone help me or
   direct me to some resources that allow me to achieve this. For ex,
   how to I even draw on the camera preview? Opencv requires the bitmap
   to do all the image processing so which view should I use (ex:
   SurfaceView, TextureView, PreviewView, etc...)? I have already tried most of them, but they all seem to give errors here and there.
2. This is not an immediate concern, but originally I was using OpenCV to make this
   app but my goal was to eventually implement it from scratch since
   using OpenCV considerably increases the APK size. I am a little
   familiar with some of the algorithms and their workings (ex: Canny
   edge, Harris Corner, inverse perspective transform, etc) but I need
   help to actually implement them in android (preferably java) since that is where I am completely lost.

Even though I am completely new to Kotlin, I read most of the documentation on Kotlin, watched the CameraX google keynote events and went through the codelabs tutorial for setting up kotlin. When I understood all this, I looked at the Official sample app provided by google called CameraX Basic on github, I was completely lost. They put so much on there that it is hard for me to even understand it. An no matter where I look, not a single decent example suits my needs. Plus, on their docs, they have implementations in both kotlin and java but they only have the sample app in java.

In summary, I am not able to understand how to add my own ImageAnalysis to CameraX to scan a document and save the image (so I can provide more options later such as export to pdf, etc...)

Comment: i understand your frustration and feeling lost, but your question is too broad for us to help you here. you'll have to start somewhere and then ask a more specific question, unfortunately

Comment: I have a done it with tflite and mlkit in java, but not opencv..

Comment: can you then just help with adding graphics to the preview of CameraX. Once I figure that out, I will tackle the next issue

Comment: @Felix can you share any resources or sites that helped you in this. Also, and this is the primary issue for me, how did you integrate image analysis with the camera API and how did you manage to draw the border of the page in the camera preview?

Comment: @Ayush Koul have a look at my github repo [link](https://github.com/FelixAtGitHub?tab=repositories)

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is bigger `OpenCV` size. If you compile all the modules it would consume over 100MB (3.x version). But if you want to image processing than `imgproc` should suffice your needs. You can compile `imgproc` alone (around 4-5MB) by switching it `ON` and rest other modules to `OFF` using following command:

```
// Clone opencv git repo
$ git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
$ cd opencv

// Checkout the version that you need, example 3.4.3, ...
$ git checkout 3.4.3

// Create a build directory
$ mkdir build
$ cd build 

// Run cmake command
$ cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../platforms/android/android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a \
-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=23 \
-D WITH_CUDA=OFF \
-D WITH_MATLAB=OFF \
-D BUILD_ANDROID_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D BUILD_DOCS=OFF \
-D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
-D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
-D ANDROID_STL=c++_shared \
-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_objdetect=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_video=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_features2d=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_flann=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_ml=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_photo=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_python=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_shape=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_superres=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_ts=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_videostab=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_imgproc=ON \
..

// Build the repo
$ make

// After successful compilation, install the libraies
$ sudo make install
```

NOTE: To compile opencv build, you need to have build tools like android `ndk, cmake, etc` installed. For more information, please refer to opencv Android building process.

There are quite a few settings, please select them as you need. You can also compile with another option [here](https://medium.com/@tomdeore/opencv-on-android-tiny-with-optimization-enabled-932460acfe38)

Comment: I am sorry, I am a bit new to this. Can you elaborate how and where I run this command? Also, the ".." at the end part of the command or is it just suggesting that the list goes on?

Comment: ".." suggest that my CMakeList file at ./opencv/ whereas we are in directory ./opencv/build/ Please refer to [link](https://medium.com/@tomdeore/opencv-on-android-tiny-with-optimization-enabled-932460acfe38) i provided to above